# Facebook API replaces part of URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am querying facebook posts of a specific fb-page and reading the posts to view them on a website. In a new post they've just created, there's a URL that links to an external page. Normally, facebooks API delivers this link just as is.

But this time, it replaces a part of that URL with a random(?) number. The link that's in the post is: www.roboterwelt.de/magazin/videos/10-roboter-die-die-welt-veraendern-werden/ and what i am getting is www.roboterwelt.de/10153713783568127/videos/10-roboter-die-die-welt-veraendern-werden/

This is my query URL (the app is not running via any Facebook SDK): graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=name,picture,posts.limit(100){comments.summary(true),likes.limit(0).summary(true),link,full_picture,created_time,id,message,type}&access_token=*

The fb-post i am working with is https://www.facebook.com/markedingplus/posts/664595060338842

Do I have to send any other paramters? Does anyone know what that number is?

Comment: Can you give us the URL to the Facebook post, or the link that it contains?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i added them in the question.
https://www.facebook.com/markedingplus/posts/664595060338842 is the fb-post and this is the URL it links to: http://www.roboterwelt.de/magazin/videos/10-roboter-die-die-welt-veraendern-werden/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=167157100082643_664595060338842%3Ffields%3Dlink&version=v2.5 gives me the link “as is”, whereas when I query the page’s feed like you do, I get the wrong version as you said. You should file a bug report for this. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: thanks again for your help, just reported the bug